# Loop between a <div> and a <div title="Page"> in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have looked at cycle() but it has problem formatting when i do:

```
<%= cycle('<div title="Pages">', <div>) %>
```

I have done this:

```
<div id="mybook">
  <% @print.document_images_list.each do |image| %>
  <%= cycle('<div title="Pages">', '<div>') %>
      <%= image_tag image %>
  </div>

  <% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

and the HTML output shows something like:

```
 &lt;div title=&quot;Pages&quot;&gt;
```

and

```
  &lt;div&gt;
```

I have looked at .each_slice enumerator and (1..x).each but i am not sure how to do about this.

(I need it without "title" in div as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 <%= raw cycle('<div title="Pages">', '<div>') %>
```

or

```
 <%= cycle('<div title="Pages">', '<div>').html_safe %>
```

Comment: Yup. it works! Thanks!

Weird thing i never saw the raw part in the documentation though. :(

Comment: I just added to the answer , maybe that will help explain